# Genymotion TcpStream::connect() errno=111

Tags: android

I am trying the genymotion (free) with RSS Feed and I get this error:

```
12-29 16:55:42.132      119-128/? E/eglCodecCommon﹕ TcpStream::connect() - connect() errno=111
12-29 16:55:42.132      119-128/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (TcpStream)!!!
12-29 16:55:42.132      119-128/? E/EGL_genymotion﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
```

about 100 times

I have a bridged network configured to adapter 2

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the Exchange service.

By default, this service does not come with any account configured, the exchange service try to connect to the internet without any credentials and fail.

You can disable it and you will not see this issue again.